c# - not jumping sometimes in unity game
I'm fairly new to unity, and I tried making a 2d platformer game. For some reason, the player only jumps sometimes when I press the spacebar but sometimes it doesn't. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private float Move;

    public bool isJumping;

    public float jump;
    public Vector2 boxSize;
    public float castDistance;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    bool grounded;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * Move, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded())
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
            Debug.Log("jump");
        }
    }

    public bool isGrounded()
    {
        if (Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxSize, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position - transform.up * castDistance, boxSize);
    }

I tried to figure out what was wrong, and I figured out that it had something to do with the ground check true/false but I can't figure out where.

so debug it, what do you see?

Hi, Have you tried to use ForceMode2D.Impulse?

I suggest you avoid the if for isGrounded. You can simply return the value of the BoxCast

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to check [ask] and note how to write a [mre]. Consider: does it help visitors answer your question by including the OnDrawGizmos function in your example? The quality of the question would be improved if that function were to be omitted, or perhaps if you explained how it is relevant to the question at hand.
